# Vignette output missing despite no errors

Tags: r, devtools

I am writing [an R package](https://github.com/alan-turing-institute/PosteriorBootstrap) with this vignette title:

```
---
title: "Adaptive non-parametric learning"
author: "..."
date: "`r Sys.Date()`"
output: rmarkdown::html_vignette
vignette: >
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Adaptive non-parametric learning}
  %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown_notangle}
  %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---
```

I added `rmarkdown_notangle` to avoid running the vignette on CRAN, as the full vignette will take an hour to run (even though now I am testing and it takes 2 minutes).

I compile the package with:

```sh
Rscript -e "devtools::document();devtools::check();devtools::build();devtools::install();"
```

The output shows:

```
...
─  installing the package to build vignettes
✔  creating vignettes (1m 48.8s)
...
✔  checking files in ‘vignettes’ ...
...
✔  checking for unstated dependencies in vignettes ...
✔  checking package vignettes in ‘inst/doc’
✔  checking re-building of vignette outputs (1m 47.9s)
...
─  installing the package to build vignettes
✔  creating vignettes (1m 49.5s)
...
** installing vignettes
** testing if installed package can be loaded
* DONE (PosteriorBootstrap)
Reloading attached PosteriorBootstrap
```

But the `doc/` directory is empty, the `inst/doc` directory does not exist, and when I import the package, no vignettes are installed:

```r
> library(PosteriorBootstrap)
> browseVignettes(package="PosteriorBootstrap")
No vignettes found by browseVignettes(package = "PosteriorBootstrap")
> vignette("Adaptive Non-parametric learning")
Warning message:
vignette ‘Adaptive Non-parametric learning’ not found
```

I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171888/no-vignettes-found-by-browsevignettes-where-they-actually-are-there) that suggests using `%\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown}`, which I use, and `install_github(..., build_vignettes=TRUE)`, which I don't since I build it locally.

Where is the vignette output?

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to change the default `build_vignettes = FALSE` in `devtools::install()`:

```r
devtools::install(build_vignettes = TRUE)
```

Then do `browseVignettes(package = "package_name")` to show the vignettes, e.g. on a browser if you use R on the command line.

I found the solution from [a comment in the thread I quoted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32171888/no-vignettes-found-by-browsevignettes-where-they-actually-are-there#comment-52343115), which suggested the same solution for `devtools::install_github()`.

I could not find the vignette output created by `devtools::check()` and `devtools::build()`.